# Setup route in Laravel 5 for CKEditor to work with CKFinder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

Hello i am trying to integrate the CKFinder with CKEditor in a laravel project. I have made following settings in my config.js file of CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    config.uiColor = '#ffffff';
    config.removePlugins = 'forms, div, save, print, preview, newpage, _cut, bidi, showblocks, about, undo, redo, removeformat';


    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';

};
```

Then i started to get `Browse Server` button as well. But i dont know why i am not able to access it. I guess i need to setup route to access it, correct?

Here i what error i am getting.

[image]

Any suggestions how i can setup the route for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this the path to the file `public/pages/kcfinder/browse.php` relative to the project directory? Or is it `public/kcfinder/browse.php`?

Comment: it is public/kcfinder/browse.php

Comment: I have a route in between 'pages'

Comment: What do you mean you _"have a route in between pages'"_? If you have a route definition that you think is relevant to the question please edit and include it in your question. Either way, I belive you problem may stem from the way you include the file browser paths, more exactly that you define them as being relative to the current path. Instead you should make them relative to the root path by adding `/` at the beggining like this `/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files` (of course add the slash `/` to all six lines to that include the `browse.php` or `upload.php` files).

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor_ckf',    
{    
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: "{{ asset('ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Files') }}",
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: "{{ asset('ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Images') }}",
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: "{{ asset('ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Flash') }}",
    filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{ asset('ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files') }}",
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "{{ asset('ckfinder/core/connctor/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images') }}",
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: "{{ asset('ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash') }}"
});
```

Comment: how can you use this `{{ asset('') }}` in a `JS` file

Comment: I use this code in my script .blade file not in config.js file

Answer (score 0):

You're using a **KC**finder configuration file with **CK**finder. Make sure you're not mixing up both file managers.